# Table with a header and column list

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am facing a challenge in writing a formula that matches each project name to the corresponding company name in table A. The project names are unique values and do not repeat within the table range.

| Project1   |
| Project2   |
| Project3   |
| Project4   |

This is the table A.

| Company1 | Company2 |
| --- | --- |
| Project1 | Project2 |
| Project3 | Project4 |

Is there any way I can obtain the values in the following result using a formula in Google Sheets?

| Company | Project |
| --- | --- |
| Company1 | Project1 |
| Company1 | Project3 |
| Company2 | Project2 |
| Company2 | Project4 |

I wrote this formula to retrieve the project names:

```
=FILTER(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(B3:Q30)), UNIQUE(FLATTEN(B3:Q30))<>"")
```

The range of the table is larger (B2:Q30, including headers from B2:Q2) and providing it will not affect the formulae.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's what you can try:

```cpp
=SORT(QUERY(SPLIT(TOCOL(A1:B1&"|"&A2:B),"|"),"where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image]

Comment: ziad.net, thank you so much for the help. You are a lifesaver. The formula works perfectly.